# package showing the approximate location of figures

Tags: floats

I must woken up stupid. There is a package which replaces figures by something like:

[figure 1 approximately here]

But I can't find it googling and searching.
Can anybody give me the name, please?

Thanks
Karl

Comment: `draft` option from `graphicx` package, "do not
include the graphic, but leave the correct space, and print the filename"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you are searching package [`endfloat`](http://ctan.org/pkg/endfoat):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{endfloat}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\section{Example}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{example-image}
  \caption{An Example Image}
\end{figure}
\Blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

results in:

[image]

at the `figure` location and prints the figure at the very end of the document.